# How to share secret key by different applications

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt/decrypt some text using symmetric key cryptography. I am using classes provided by apache shiro library.(org.apache.shiro.crypto.DefaultBlockCipherService)

I have multiple instances of my server running that would be encrypting and decrypting the texts. I want to understand how can I share the secret key across multiple instances of application so that texts encrypted by one can be decrypted by other.

How can I serialize the key to a file and again generate the key from the file?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer I'm giving is more in the deployment/operational space but could solve your issue. I'm looking at [the superclass](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/crypto/CipherService.html#encrypt(byte[],%20byte[])) for reference, which has the encrypt and decrypt implementations containing the key.

You could:

1. Hand all of the instances of the app a string representing that deployment as an environment variable. (Maybe its the revision number deployed or hashed date or something).
2. Develop your application to consume and hash this value using an algorithm of your choice at startup. This is your key that's made available as a singleton to your code which encrypts/decrypts messages.
3. Ensure your deployment mechanism (whether its you manually, or some code) gives all of the instances the same value. (i.e. choose something consistent to the deployment or code deployed)

This approach ensures that the actual key is obfuscated by your code (it won't be the ENV variable ver-batim) and that you can rotate it often to keep it secure.

Hope thats what you were looking for.